# Order by using rounded column

Tags: sql, oracle, rounding, sql-order-by

I want to print the following result

```
Oceania        109189 
South America  147435 
Europe         175138 
Africa         274439 
Asia           693038
```

My query is

```
select co.Continent bb, round(avg(ci.Population)) as aa
from Country co
  FULL OUTER JOIN City ci ON co.Code = ci.CountryCode
group by co.Continent
having (count(ci.ID)<>0 and co.Continent is not null)
order by aa asc;
```

and its displaying following result

```
Africa         274439 
Asia           693038 
Europe         175138 
Oceania        109190 
South America  147435
```

How can I order the result using the rounded value ????

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Very odd. Move the select to having as a derived table, and then try ORDER BY.

Comment: didn't get ur point.....

Comment: See Blakes Seven's answer and you'll see what I meant!

Comment: i tried that earlier. but it didn't worked :(

Comment: To be completely honest, I find that hard to believe. As Thorsten Kettner pointed out in their answer - probably your host application is doing something strange. Try running the query in SQL/Plus and add the results to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
select bb, round(aa) as aa from (
    select co.Continent bb, avg(ci.Population) as aa
    from Country co
    FULL OUTER JOIN City ci ON co.Code = ci.CountryCode
    group by co.Continent
    having (count(ci.ID)<>0 and co.Continent is not null)
)T
order by round(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why the ORDER BY should not work. Your query is correct. Obviously you get the records ordered by co.Continent, though.

So it must be your app performing this sort after getting the results from the DBMS. An auto-sorting listbox or the like, maybe?

Comment: Should this not be a comment? Sure there likely is something else ordering the result shown. But I do have to ask.

Comment: @Blakes Seven: No, this is the answer. Don't doubt the query, check the app :-)

Comment: Don't know what to say other than "if the shoe fits". So I suppose if the question is lacking in all the information then a fair supposition is that the answer lies in stating that something lies outside out what is said. Learning experience I guess.

Comment: @Blakes Seven: The only other possible assumption (i.e. your assumption :-) I see, would be a bug in his Oracle DBMS. I don't find that likely. There is an ORDER BY clause, and the data shown *is* sorted, but differently. A sort after the sort, obviously. Raj gave all the information he considered relevant, the SQL and the result, so I don't blame him.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this simply work? :

```
  select co.continent bb, round (avg (ci.population)) as aa
    from country co full outer join city ci on co.code = ci.countrycode
group by co.continent
  having (count (ci.id) <> 0 and co.continent is not null)
order by round (avg (ci.population)) asc;
```